# Updating a single node in a xml file depending on a specific attribute in php

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file named test.xml with the following structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <markers>
       <marker id="1" name="12" signal="23"/>
       <marker id="2" name="12" signal="5"/>
       <marker id="3" name="12" signal="6"/>
       <marker id="4" name="12" signal="0"/>
</markers>
```

I make an ajax request to my server code where I sent an `ID` and want to increase the `signal` attribute in `test.xml` by 1.

For example if I send `id=3` then the `signal` attribute of the `marker` node with `id` of `3` should get `7` and the file should be saved.
I don't want to rewrite the whole file due to some issues but only update an attribute.

I tried this but I think it's far away from the right answer. Can anyone help?

```
$id=$_POST['id'];

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('test.xml');

foreach( $xml->xpath( 'marker' ) as $xml_row ){
    if( $xml_row->attributes( 'id' ) == $id ){
        $xml_row->attr( 'signals ') = $xml_row->attributes( 'signals' ) + 1;

    }
}
$xml->saveXML( 'test.xml' );
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: I get internal server error 500

Comment: 500 error should log an error in your error.log - if you post this it will help.

Comment: I posted the solution as an answer below but the problem was here:   $xml_row->attr( 'signals ') = $xml_row->attributes( 'signals' ) + 1;   where I was trying to get the value of the attribute like this which is completely wrong. I changed the class which I used from simpleXml to DOMDocument and wrote the answer like you see below. Anyways thanks for paying attention to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself:

```
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load('test.xml');
foreach ($xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('marker') as $feeditem) {
    if($feeditem->getAttribute('id')==$id){
        $sig=$feeditem->getAttribute('signal');
        $sig++;
        $feeditem->setAttribute('signal',$sig);
    }


}
$xmldoc->save('test.xml');
```